# Joining multiple cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've converted a PDF'd table into Word in order to convert that into Excel.  But text in each cell was broken into several cells.  I know how to join cells, but that can only be done one cell at a time -- my document is 150 pages long with 8 columns!  Is there an easier way than separately joining each item one at a time?  Your discussion about removing paragraph codes and line endings doesn't help; that is not the problem as there aren't any line endings, and removing paragraph codes didn't make any difference.

Comment: If you are referring to some previous discussion on Super User, please link to it.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Why not just convert the pdf into a csv?

Comment: Right click on the PDF table and select `Copy As Table` option and paste in Excel

Answer (score 1):

Any large repetitive task like the one you described can only be automated if there is a distinct characteristic that the computer can identify. E.g. If the text was broken on each 5th word. If you can identify this, then you can use a macro in VBA to correct the issue. Of course this is not always the case, but we cannot know for sure with the limited information you have given us.

I would suggest that instead of using word, you directly convert from PDF to Excel. There are multiple free online services available for you. Be warned however, that unless the PDF is nothing but a table, it will not convert properly. Thus please let us know in what way it messed up after conversion and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

With this app, you can determinate where cell starts/ends before conversion:
http://www.abbyy.com/finereader/

If this is just for single use, you can do it on trial I think.